# Ionic 2 - Handling More Complicated Touch Release (Exit) Events

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

Alrighty, so let's start with the vision and I'll get into the implementation.

Basically, I'm developing an application with four control buttons in the toolbar.

[image]

We'll focus on two buttons. The left most button moves the character left. The second-most-left button moves the character up. So we have a couple obvious situations:

- User taps the left button. The character moves left.
- User releases the left button. The character stops moving left.
- User taps the left button *and* the up button. The character moves left and up.

Here's how I'm currently handling that:

```html
<button ion-button 
            (touchstart)="ButtonPress('left');"
            (touchend)="ButtonRelease('left');"
            color="light" style="font-family:courier; font-size:28px; padding:15px; height:auto;">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropleft"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button 
            (touchstart)="ButtonPress('up');"
            (touchend)="ButtonRelease('up');"
            color="light" style="font-family:courier; font-size:28px; padding:15px; height:auto;">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropup"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button 
            (touchstart)="ButtonPress('down');"
            (touchend)="ButtonRelease('down');"
            color="light" style="font-family:courier; font-size:28px; padding:15px; height:auto;">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropdown"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button 
            (touchstart)="ButtonPress('right');"
            (touchend)="ButtonRelease('right');"
            color="light" style="font-family:courier; font-size:28px; padding:15px; height:auto;">
        <ion-icon name="arrow-dropright"></ion-icon>
    </button>
```

The tricky part was getting the touch release events to trigger, but this code officially works. It does exactly what is expected. When a touch is started we move, when a touch is ended we stop.

**But (there's always a 'But')**

There is one event that isn't handled, and which only came up once I got this built on my phone.

Imagine the user performs the following:

- The touch the left button. The character starts moving left.
- They slide their finger (without lifting) onto the up button.

Now, what *should* happen is:

- User is no longer on the left button, so stop moving left.
- User is now touching the up button, so start moving up.

What instead happens is:

- User continues moving left (because the touch was never ended).
- User doesn't move up (because the touch was never started).

**I need to rewrite these events in such a way that sliding the finger onto or off of a button triggers the start/end events. Thoughts?**